# sliderValueDidChange getting called multiple times

Tags: ios, objective-c, uislider

I have a UISlider and I'd like to slide 3 UILabels below it along with the slider, as well as update their values, which are dependent on the slider value. When dragging the slider, the location flashes back and forth between where it should be and back to the center position. Inserting a breakpoint, for a very minute amount, the sliderValueDidChange method gets called multiple times and the sliderValue shows different values. Any ideas?

```
- (IBAction)sliderValueDidChange:(UISlider *)sender {
// Update the labels
float sliderValue = sender.value;
percentSplitLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f%@", sliderValue * 100, @"%"];
themSplitValueLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%.2f", @"$", totalToBeAddedToTabValue];
meSplitValueLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%.2f", @"$", totalBillValue - totalToBeAddedToTabValue];

// Reposition the numbers below
CGRect sliderFrame = splitBillSlider.frame;
percentSplitLabel.center = CGPointMake(sliderFrame.origin.x - sliderFrame.size.width/2.0 + sliderFrame.size.width * sliderValue + 150, percentSplitLabel.center.y);
themSplitValueLabel.center = CGPointMake(percentSplitLabel.center.x + percentSplitLabel.frame.size.width + 10, percentSplitLabel.center.y);
meSplitValueLabel.center = CGPointMake(percentSplitLabel.center.x - percentSplitLabel.frame.size.width, percentSplitLabel.center.y);
```

Comment: Not an Xcode question. -------- IIRC there's a `continuous` property on `UISlider` that you can set to `NO`.

Comment: But I want it to update continuously so that as you slide it the values below slide along.

Comment: Do you use Auto Layout in your view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Auto Layout in your views try to disable it (File inspector > Uncheck “Enable Autolayout”).

Comment: Wow... I was (though unintentionally). Turning autolayout off fixed it right away. Thanks! Do you have an explanation for why this was the problem?

Comment: @JamesPMason, Autolayout is why autolayout is the problem. Better if it wasn't enabled by default... a good practice is to disable it on all new projects unless you know that you need it (if you are not sure whether you need it, you don't need it).

Comment: When Auto Layout is enabled, the `frame`s of subviews are set automatically according to the constraints. So what was happening is that your code and Auto Layout were changing the position of the labels which made the flash you was seeing.

Comment: Since Apple is pushing for developers to use auto layout, you should be aware of the auto layout version of the solution to this problem: create IBOutlets to your constraints (or create them in code), and then update the constraints, instead of the frames, when you drag your slider.

Comment: @ZevEisenberg Good point, although I think changing the frame directly is more effective in this specific case than changing the constraints on every little change.

Comment: Hejazi, why do you think that? Changing a constraint is no more difficult or processor intensive than changing the frame, and the code is quite a bit shorter. Using auto layout, as @Zev said, is the way Apple is moving, so it behooves developers to learn to deal with it rather than turning it off.